# SVN not storing credentials

Tags: svn

Recently upgrade to a new machine and svn is giving me a headache

I have enabled the appropriate settings in `~./subversion/server` and given all permissions (777) to the folder but still svn persists to not save passwords for our repo. What's more confusing is it is not prompting me to save password when I do a c/o?

I have a few dev apps that run svn commands so I need these credentials saved

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the mistake I made was assuming my credentials would be saved when I was using git svn commands. I did a basic `svn co` with the `--username --password` and it was successfully saved.

Schoolboy error.